# ErrorException Undefined variable: expR

Tags: laravel

No entiendo por qué da el error si la variable expR sí está definida

Estoy usando Laravel 7 y me da este error:
ErrorException
Undefined variable: expR

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SummaryReport extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $expR = 'nada';

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail.expenseReport', [
            'report' => $expR
        ]);
    }
}
```

No logro entender cuál es el problema :(
Desde ya agradezco su tiempo
Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba usando la pseudovariable `$this` para indicar el contexto de la propiedad que tratas de usar; es decir que quede así:

```
 return $this->view('mail.expenseReport', [
            'report' => $this->expR
        ]);
```

Ya que dicha propiedad esta declarada a nivel o contexto de tu modelo/clase `SummaryReport`

Comment: Sí, había tratado antes pero no funcionó, sin embargo traté con  
  
$this->$expR  
  
En vez de 
  
$this->expR  
  
Como debería ser jaja  
Gracias! un saludo!